# IE only: 10 $digest() iterations reached ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am getting this error on page load where I am using ng-grid. Does anybody get any clue from the below error, on why I am getting this error.

These are just the first few lines of the error

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["renderedColumns; 
newVal: [{\"width\":25,\"groupIndex\":0,\"isGroupedBy\":false,\"minWidth\":50,\"maxWidth\":9000,\"headerRowHeight\":30,\"displayName\":\"\\u2714\",\"index\":0,\"cellFilter\":\"\",\"field\":\"\\u2714\",\"visible\":true,\"sortable\":false,\"resizable\":false,\"pinnable\":false,\"originalIndex\":0,\"groupable\":false,\"cursor\":\"default\",\"headerCellTemplate\":\"<input class=\\\"ngSelectionHeader\\\" type=\\\"checkbox\\\" ng-show=\\\"multiSelect\\\" ng-model=\\\"allSelected\\\" ng-change=\\\"toggleSelectAll(allSelected)\\\"/>\",\"cellTemplate\":\"<div class=\\\"ngSelectionCell\\\"><input tabindex=\\\"-1\\\" class=\\\"ngSelectionCheckbox\\\" type=\\\"checkbox\\\" ng-checked=\\\"row.selected\\\" /></div>\"}]; 

oldVal: [{\"width\":25,\"groupIndex\":0,\"isGroupedBy\":false,\"minWidth\":50,\"maxWidth\":9000,\"headerRowHeight\":30,\"displayName\":\"\\u2714\",\"index\":0,\"cellFilter\":\"\",\"field\":\"\\u2714\",\"visible\":true,\"sortable\":false,\"resizable\":false,\"pinnable\":false,\"originalIndex\":0,\"groupable\":false,\"cursor\":\"default\",\"headerCellTemplate\":\"<input class=\\\"ngSelectionHeader\\\" type=\\\"checkbox\\\" ng-show=\\\"multiSelect\\\" ng-model=\\\"allSelected\\\" ng-change=\\\"toggleSelectAll(allSelected)\\\"/>\",\"cellTemplate\":\"<div class=\\\"ngSelectionCell\\\"><input tabindex=\\\"-1\\\" class=\\\"ngSelectionCheckbox\\\" type=\\\"checkbox\\\" ng-checked=\\\"row.selected\\\" /></div>\"}]","viewportStyle();
```

Comment: Can you ad HTML/JS source or (even better) create Plunker/JSFiddle snippet to illustrate problem?